# How can I ping a host that is not a Lan-Segment but is on the same internal network?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ping

I have a problem where I have two computers, win and ubuntu, on the same internal network, and win can ping ubuntu but not the other way around (timeout)?

*(Lan Segment is a physical portion of a **local area network** (LAN) that is separated from other portions by bridges or routers.)*

For example, the IP address of my win machine is `192.168.202.153`, subnet mask `255.255.255.0`, gateway `192.168.202.254`. The IP address of my ubuntu machine is `192.168.45.170`, subnet mask `255.255.255.0`, gateway `192.168. 45.1`

I have learned from my research that in order to ping win on ubuntu, I should add the target network segment to the gateway that passes through ubuntu in the router table, i.e. add the routing information with the following command. During this time, I also turned off Win's firewall.

```bash
sudo route add -net 192.168.202.0/24 gw 192.168.45.1
```

I then tried to ping through the gateway and could not ping through the following win host ip.

```bash
ping 192.168.202.254
```

output:

```
PING 192.168.202.254 (192.168.202.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.202.254: icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time=0.394 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.202.254: icmp_seq=2 ttl=254 time=0.494 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.202.254: icmp_seq=3 ttl=254 time=0.468 ms
...
```

then,test ping <win_ip>.

```bash
ping 192.168.202.153
```

output:

```
PING 192.168.202.153 (192.168.202.153) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Then it keeps hanging without response.

---

Also, I tried the following command:

```bash
tracepath 192.168.202.153
```

output:

```
 1?: [LOCALHOST] pmtu 1500
 1: _gateway 14.221ms 
 1: _gateway 2.184ms 
 2: 192.168.202.153 0.501ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 1500 hops 2 back 5
```